# How to call accessor in javascript blade laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have set an accessor in the model

```
public function getDayInfoAttribute()
{
    $fromDate = $this->program->from_date;
    $toDate = $this->program->to_date;
    $period = CarbonPeriod::create($fromDate, $toDate);
    $days = [];
    foreach ($period as $p) {
        $day = verta($p)->formatWord('l');
        $dayOfWeek = verta($p)->dayOfWeek;
        $days[$dayOfWeek]=[
            'id' => $dayOfWeek,
            'day' => $day,
            'date' => $p->format('Y-m-d')
        ];
    }
    return $days;
}
```

My javascript codes are written in blade.

Now I want to call it in javascript code.

```
<script>
     let fields =@json($prgFields);
     fields.day_info['id'];
</script>
```

Please help if you have any idea to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: the controller calls this getter then passe it to the vue, you can use hidden field for your data in html then get them by getElementById() inside JS script

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> If you would like these computed values to be added to the array / JSON representations of your model, [you will need to append them](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json).

```php
class PrgField
{
    protected $appends = [ 'dayInfo' ];
}
```

Comment: And how to call it in javascript code?

Comment: You can't _call_ PHP methods in JavaScript. PHP only returns the JSON representation of model so you must append everything, you'll need in JavaScript when you return the model to the client.